# Adding Icon@2x.png to SVN

Tags: svn, ios4

I was trying add the retina icon to SVN but seem to have trouble checking it in.

I tried 
svn add Icon@2x.png
svn add Icon\@2x.png 
but neither of them works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
RS

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I typed in `svn add "Icon@2x.png"` and got 
`svn: warning: 'Icon' not found`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do this ...

```
svn add Icon@2x.png@
```

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't matter how you escape the '@' symbol, the reason this happens is because SVN thinks the last '@' is to specify a revision number (@REV format). To get around it you need to put another '@' symbol at the end of the file-name.

```
svn add Icon@2x.png@
```

If you need to add multiple files it can be a pain to type them all in manually, but you can use xargs to automate this:

```
ls *2x.png | xargs -I x svn add x@
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't be better to make it recursive? (Just suggestion for / update of previous answer)

```
 find . -name "*2x.png" |xargs -I x svn add x@
```