# How to svn add filename@2.png?

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I am trying to add my existing xcode project to svn. I used the command

```
svn add projectFolder/*
```

But I get a problem with all files that has a @-character in the name, e.g., `Default@2.png` . How can I add those files to subversion?

Comment: i asked the same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/183020/how-to-escape-the-at-sign-in-bash

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Check out the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6118391/549092)

Comment: Okey, ls *2x.png | xargs -I x svn add x@ did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding **@** at the end of file solves the problem according to [this](http://www.jroller.com/evans/entry/adding_files_with_in_file)

Comment: Please note: You dont have to rename the file, just add the '@' to the command in terminal